# How do I map AJAX to servlet without web.xml

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

TL;DR: Putting @WebServlet("/Find-Customers") at the beginning of a servlet (deployed through Tomcat 7) is not mapping the servlet to host:port/webproject/Find-Customers even though the servlet is in the src folder.

I am trying to call the servlet using @WebServlet("/..."), which I've done in the past but somehow something is going wrong this time. I've never used web.xml and it's worked just fine. I used Ajax POST method in ajaxFxns.js and fed in "Find-Customers" as the address and the following in Java:

```
package coreservlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet("/Find-Customers")
public class ShowCustomers extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {


response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

// more code here

}

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
  }
}
```

Firebug says 404 Not Found when it comes to "/Find-Customers" so as far as I know it means that the @WebServlet function is not appropriately mapping the servlet to localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers. Here is the directory structure (with irrelevant things taken out):

```
Webproject
--src
  --coreservlets
    --ShowCustomers.java
--WebContent
  --scripts
    --ajaxFxns.js
  --index.html
```

Should I have done something special when I created my coreservlets folder, or how do I go about debugging this in a developer environment (I'm using Eclipse)? Web.xml implementation hasn't really gone smoothly either which is why I'm asking how to go without it. Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Are you seeing the context path in the URL ? When debugging in Firefox ?

Comment: do you mean when it says "POST http://localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers" in the console? This doesn't help me that much because my other projects (which work) give the same pattern.

Comment: Which server make/version is this webapp deployed to? `@WebServlet` works only in Servlet 3.0 capable containers and newer. The whole ajax story seems unnecessary as you'd already get the very same HTTP 404 error problem when just entering servlet's URL straight in browser's address bar, right? You could then simply reduce that JS/ajax noise from the question to make it better focused (as you've excluded JS from being the probable cause).

Comment: Sure, I'm new to this and just wanted to eliminate all possibilities. I'm using Tomcat 7 and Java 8. It's worked in previous projects using the same materials.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the Ajax code?
There can be a problem in the URL of Ajax call.
For example consider below two cases:

1. Using "/Find-Customers" as a URL in Ajax call. It will target a URL like :  localhost:8080/Find-Customers, which is not correct.
2. Using "Find-Customers" as a URL in Ajax call. It will target a URL like :.  localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers, which is correct.

The Ajax call works fine for the the ShowCustomers Servlet you posted with below index.html and ajaxFxns.js

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ajaxFxns.js"></script>
        <title>Ajax post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajaxFxns.js:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "Find-Customers", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: I did not put in the "/" and got "localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers 404 not found." Reading tutorials I have no idea why this would happen if I clearly have @WebServlet("/Find-Customers") at the beginning of my Java script. @WebServlet("/Find-Customers") should automatically make it accessible at localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers...as long as it's in the source folder...no?

Comment: @user1764359 Yes, you are right. @WebServlet("/Find-Customers") should make it accessible at localhost:8080/webproject/Find-Customers.
It is even working with the code you have posted with the same project structure.

Comment: Well then I am stuck :( I don't think it will help, but I've reposted the ajax code just in case. I tried this on a non-local server with Tomcat 7 set up, no luck

Comment: i seem to have fixed it by just setting up a new web project and pasting in my old code--although i have no idea what was going on in the first place! thank you for your help! :)